# Chrome extensions: Adding to the share to menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've seen screenshots with other items added to the url sharing menu but I've no idea how? Is there an API for web extensions for this? I would like to be able to customise this for Desktop version.

Searching for the docs for such a feature is a nightmare.

[image: screenshot of chrome share menu]

Comment: There's no such API for extensions. This menu is hardcoded in the built-in UI, the contents [depends on country and changes on updates](https://crsrc.org/chrome/browser/share/core/share_targets.cc).

Comment: I've looked at one extension that does what you want: [Share with for Google Chrome (TM!)](https://github.com/chrisephoto/share-with-for-google-chrome) It doesn't actually customize the [Share button](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10051760?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). What it does is add an action with a [popup](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/user_interface/#popup) that replicates the Share button.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you. Odd how they decide by country etc. Just assumed if the list was different, apps could plug into that functionality.